# Post method I am getting nullpointer error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have an object defined as below:

```
public class MappingObject {
        public SelectList cSelectlist { get; set; }
        public SelectList sSelectlist { get; set; }
}
```

This object is passed to a view successfully. I get a null pointer error when I try to read data in my post method as below.

```
public ActionResult Edit(MappingObject mo)  {
    foreach(SelectListItem cc in mo.cSelectlist){
        Debug.WriteLine("Selected value is " +cc.Text);
    }
    return View();
}
```

View code is :

```
@using myProject.Models;

@model myProject.Models.MappingObject
@{ 
    SelectList consList = Model.cSelectlist;
    SelectList scopeList = Model.sSelectlist;
}
```

And I am using MVC framework.

Comment: check if mo object in Edit action has a value and if yes, Check cc object in your foreach loop

Comment: Do you mean `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: When you say *I get an error*, the very next thing you should provide in your question is the **exact error message** you're seeing. It's on the screen right in front of you, and there is absolutely no reason you should not provide it so we have that information as well.

Comment: You don't even say what framework you are using. How would anyone know what is going on?

Comment: definitely the object you are passing is null thats why you are getting 'NullReferencException' check your object that you are passing.

Comment: Check your object you are passing in method. Run you IDE in debugging mode or provide adequate information.

Comment: I am using MVC framework.

Comment: @anand which version of that framework? How are your routes setup? And don't say it in comments, say it in the question!

Answer (score -3):

To avoid unexpected errors as a quick fix, you can do below.

```
public ActionResult Edit(MappingObject mo)  {
  if(mo != null && mo.cSelectlist != null){
    foreach(SelectListItem cc in mo.cSelectlist){
       if(cc != null){
        Debug.WriteLine("Selected value is " +cc.Text);
       }  
    }
   }
  return View();
}
```

Based on your code, we can check if something is causing an issue.
**I am pretty sure there is something else that's causing the issue. Make sure to fix that aswell without leaving your code if it works with the above fix.**

Comment: solution looks to be hiding some issue at one end and making it more nasty bug later on. I simply mean `(!=null)` check to fix null reference exception is not right solution.

Comment: Agreed. And that's the reason I added a statement, "Based on your code, we can check if something is causing an issue." We have to identify the root cause rather than doing this quick fix.

Comment: Guys I didnt say this is the fix. I just said its a quick fix. Also I added a statement "Based on your code, we can check if something is causing an issue."

Comment: `mo` can also be null, right ? how quick fix will catch that ?

Comment: That condition is already added as the first check

Comment: Hi All, the object is coming from the request posted. how do I make sure the object is not null. Here is my edit view for more details.


using myProject.Models;

model myProject.Models.MappingObject
{ 
    SelectList consList = Model.cSelectlist;
    SelectList scopeList = Model.sSelectlist;
}

Comment: @anand add any information to your question, not in a comment on an answer.